# when I submit the form I am getting password is null but I am inserting it. (Laravel Livewire)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

*when I submit the form I am getting password is null but I am inserting it.  (Laravel Livewire)*

**Migration File** (This is Migration File)

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

**Model Class** (This is Model Class)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Livewire class** (This is Livewire Class)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class Authenticate extends Component
{
    public $name,$email,$password,$register = false,$login = true;

    public $rules = [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    public function resetInputFields(){
        $this->name = null;
        $this->email = null;
        $this->password = null;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.authenticate')
        ->layout('layouts.auth');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->validate();
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $this->email,'password' => $this->password]))
        {
            session()->flash('success','Login Successfully');
        }else{
            session()->flash('error','Login Failed');
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->register = !$this->register;
        $this->login = !$this->login;
    }

    public function store()
    {
       $this->validate([
       'name' => 'required',
       'email' => 'required|email',
       'password' => 'required',
       ]);
       User::create([
           'name' => $this->name,
           'email' => $this->email,
           'password' => $this->password,
       ]);
       session()->flash('success','Registered Successfully');
       $this->resetInputFields();
    }
}
```

**Blade File** (This is my html file)

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
    {{session('error')}}
@elseif(session()->has('success'))
    {{session('success')}}
@endif

@if($register)
<form class="login100-form" wire:submit.prevent="store">
                <span class="login100-form-title">
                    Member Register
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 ">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" placeholder="Name" wire:model="name">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                    <span class="symbol-input100">
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 ">
                    <input class="input100" type="email" placeholder="Email"  wire:model="email">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                    <span class="symbol-input100"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 ">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" placeholder="Password" wire:model="password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    <span style="color:red">@error('password'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                    <span class="symbol-input100"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </div>
                
                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">Register</button>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                    <button class="txt2" wire:click.prevent="register">Already have an account?
                        <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
</form>
@else
<form class="login100-form" wire:submit.prevent="login">
    <span class="login100-form-title">
        Member Login
    </span>
    
    <div class="wrap-input100">
        <input class="input100" type="text" wire:model="email">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100">
        <input class="input100" type="password" wire:model="password">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span style="color:red">@error('password'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Remember me</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <button class="login100-form-btn" type ="submit">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center p-t-12">
        <span class="txt1">
            Forgot
        </span>
        <a class="txt2" href="#">
            Password?
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center p-t-36">
        <button class="txt2"  wire:click.prevent="register">
            Create your Account
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
    
@endif
```

I have cross check for spelling mistake but every thing is find. I am not getting the problem

Comment: How it is possible. It's not working for me.

Comment: if you change register to true your problem on register will solved. you don't need use livewire when you want to change between register and login.